# VB.Net Designer Error (Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'.)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I have a datagrid on a form named frmTeacherload and suddenly when I run the code it came up with this error Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'. on the designer of vb. Here is my code guys I hope you can help me thanks in advance

designer code
     _
    Partial Class frmTeacherload
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.ComboBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.lblBack = New System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel()
    Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
    Me.DataGridView2 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.Name = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2 = New WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet2()
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet1 = New WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet1()
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter = New WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet1TableAdapters.tblteacherloadTableAdapter()
    Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Label4 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TextBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TextBox3 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label6 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TextBox4 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label7 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TextBox5 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label8 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TextBox6 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Label9 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TextBox7 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter1 = New WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet2TableAdapters.tblteacherloadTableAdapter()
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3 = New WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet3()
    Me.BindingSource1 = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter2 = New WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet3TableAdapters.tblteacherloadTableAdapter()
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    CType(Me.DataGridView2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.BindingSource1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Label1
    '
    Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Calligraphy", 18.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(610, 18)
    Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(217, 31)
    Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Label1.Text = "Teacher's Load"
    '
    'Label2
    '
    Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 74)
    Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
    Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(125, 13)
    Me.Label2.TabIndex = 1
    Me.Label2.Text = "Choose Teachers Name:"
    '
    'ComboBox1
    '
    Me.ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ComboBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(149, 70)
    Me.ComboBox1.Name = "ComboBox1"
    Me.ComboBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(121, 21)
    Me.ComboBox1.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'lblBack
    '
    Me.lblBack.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblBack.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(22, 30)
    Me.lblBack.Name = "lblBack"
    Me.lblBack.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 13)
    Me.lblBack.TabIndex = 94
    Me.lblBack.TabStop = True
    Me.lblBack.Text = "<<<Back"
    '
    'Panel1
    '
    Me.Panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(549, 52)
    Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
    Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(272, 10)
    Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 95
    '
    'DataGridView2
    '
    Me.DataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Me.DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.DataGridView2.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.Name, Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1, Me.NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2, Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3, Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4, Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5, Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6})
    Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
    Me.DataGridView2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(45, 97)
    Me.DataGridView2.Name = "DataGridView2"
    Me.DataGridView2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(753, 178)
    Me.DataGridView2.TabIndex = 96
    '
    'Name
    '
    Me.Name.DataPropertyName = "Name"
    Me.Name.HeaderText = "Name"
    Me.Name.Name = "Name"
    '
    'TblteacherloadDataSet2
    '
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2.DataSetName = "tblteacherloadDataSet2"
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema
    '
    'TblteacherloadDataSet1
    '
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet1.DataSetName = "tblteacherloadDataSet1"
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet1.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema
    '
    'TblteacherloadTableAdapter
    '
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = True
    '
    'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 303)
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 97
    '
    'Label3
    '
    Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(33, 306)
    Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
    Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(18, 13)
    Me.Label3.TabIndex = 98
    Me.Label3.Text = "ID"
    '
    'Label4
    '
    Me.Label4.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(33, 351)
    Me.Label4.Name = "Label4"
    Me.Label4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 13)
    Me.Label4.TabIndex = 100
    Me.Label4.Text = "Teacher's Name"
    '
    'TextBox2
    '
    Me.TextBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 348)
    Me.TextBox2.Name = "TextBox2"
    Me.TextBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox2.TabIndex = 99
    '
    'Label5
    '
    Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(337, 310)
    Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
    Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 13)
    Me.Label5.TabIndex = 104
    Me.Label5.Text = "Subject"
    '
    'TextBox3
    '
    Me.TextBox3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(123, 393)
    Me.TextBox3.Name = "TextBox3"
    Me.TextBox3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox3.TabIndex = 103
    '
    'Label6
    '
    Me.Label6.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(33, 394)
    Me.Label6.Name = "Label6"
    Me.Label6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 13)
    Me.Label6.TabIndex = 102
    Me.Label6.Text = "Section"
    '
    'TextBox4
    '
    Me.TextBox4.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(427, 303)
    Me.TextBox4.Name = "TextBox4"
    Me.TextBox4.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox4.TabIndex = 101
    '
    'Label7
    '
    Me.Label7.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(337, 393)
    Me.Label7.Name = "Label7"
    Me.Label7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(30, 13)
    Me.Label7.TabIndex = 108
    Me.Label7.Text = "Time"
    '
    'TextBox5
    '
    Me.TextBox5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(427, 345)
    Me.TextBox5.Name = "TextBox5"
    Me.TextBox5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox5.TabIndex = 107
    '
    'Label8
    '
    Me.Label8.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label8.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(337, 348)
    Me.Label8.Name = "Label8"
    Me.Label8.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(26, 13)
    Me.Label8.TabIndex = 106
    Me.Label8.Text = "Day"
    '
    'TextBox6
    '
    Me.TextBox6.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(427, 394)
    Me.TextBox6.Name = "TextBox6"
    Me.TextBox6.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox6.TabIndex = 105
    '
    'Label9
    '
    Me.Label9.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label9.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(588, 306)
    Me.Label9.Name = "Label9"
    Me.Label9.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(35, 13)
    Me.Label9.TabIndex = 112
    Me.Label9.Text = "Room"
    '
    'TextBox7
    '
    Me.TextBox7.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(678, 303)
    Me.TextBox7.Name = "TextBox7"
    Me.TextBox7.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    Me.TextBox7.TabIndex = 111
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(591, 435)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(94, 30)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 113
    Me.Button1.Text = "SUBMIT"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'TblteacherloadTableAdapter1
    '
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter1.ClearBeforeFill = True
    '
    'TblteacherloadDataSet3
    '
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3.DataSetName = "tblteacherloadDataSet3"
    Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema
    '
    'BindingSource1
    '
    Me.BindingSource1.DataMember = "tblteacherload"
    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3
    '
    'TblteacherloadTableAdapter2
    '
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter2.ClearBeforeFill = True
    '
    'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1
    '
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.DataPropertyName = "ID"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "ID"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"
    '
    'NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name"
    Me.NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Name"
    Me.NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    '
    'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2
    '
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.DataPropertyName = "Section"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.HeaderText = "Section"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"
    '
    'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3
    '
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.DataPropertyName = "Subject"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.HeaderText = "Subject"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3"
    '
    'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4
    '
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.DataPropertyName = "Day"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.HeaderText = "Day"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4"
    '
    'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5
    '
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5.DataPropertyName = "Time"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5.HeaderText = "Time"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5"
    '
    'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6
    '
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6.DataPropertyName = "Room"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6.HeaderText = "Room"
    Me.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6.Name = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6"
    '
    'frmTeacherload
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(839, 494)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label9)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox7)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label7)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox5)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label8)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox6)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label5)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox3)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label6)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox4)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label4)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Panel1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblBack)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.ComboBox1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label2)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
    Me.Name = "frmTeacherload"
    Me.Text = "First Books Learning Center"
    CType(Me.DataGridView2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.BindingSource1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents frmTeacherload As System.Windows.Forms.Form
Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label2 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents ComboBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
Friend WithEvents lblBack As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
Friend WithEvents Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
Friend WithEvents DataGridView2 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadDataSet1 As WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet1
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadBindingSource As System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadTableAdapter As WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet1TableAdapters.tblteacherloadTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Label3 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents Label4 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TextBox2 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Label5 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TextBox3 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Label6 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TextBox4 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Label7 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TextBox5 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Label8 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TextBox6 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Label9 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TextBox7 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadDataSet2 As WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet2
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadBindingSource1 As System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadTableAdapter1 As WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet2TableAdapters.tblteacherloadTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents IDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Shadows WithEvents Name As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents SectionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents SubjectDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents DayDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents TimeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents RoomDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadDataSet3 As WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet3
Friend WithEvents BindingSource1 As System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
Friend WithEvents TblteacherloadTableAdapter2 As WindowsApplication1.tblteacherloadDataSet3TableAdapters.tblteacherloadTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents NameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn4 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn5 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn6 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

End Class

frmTeacherload

```
Public Class frmTeacherload
Dim query As String
Dim y As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password='';User ID=;Data Source='" & Application.StartupPath & "/tblteacherload.accdb';"
Dim database As New clsDatabase.OleDBase(y)
Private Sub lblBack_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles lblBack.LinkClicked
    frmEnrollment.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub frmTeacherload_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TblteacherloadDataSet3.tblteacherload' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter2.Fill(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet3.tblteacherload)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TblteacherloadDataSet2.tblteacherload' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2.tblteacherload)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TblteacherloadDataSet1.tblteacherload' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet1.tblteacherload)

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
Private Sub fillDataGridView2()
    Try
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        '=================================================
        'eto lang naman ung mahalaga-> para ilabas sa datagridview ung laman ng table
        query = "Select * From tblteacherload;" ' malamang eto ung query
        database.ToDataGrid(Me.DataGridView2, query)   ' eto naman ung pang-execute
        '=================================================
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed")
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub

'eto ung mga query, dapat maayos at tama lahat ng nakasulat., pag hindi error lalabas, magingat ka sa pag-dedeclare, tignan mo mabuti ung query para tama
Private Sub add_save()
    query = "INSERT INTO `tblteacherload`(`ID`, `Name`, `Section`, `Subject`, `Day`,`Time`,`Room`) VALUES ('" _
            & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & TextBox4.Text & "', '" & TextBox5.Text & "', '" & TextBox6.Text & "', , '" & TextBox7.Text & "');"
    database.ToDataGrid(Me.DataGridView2, query)
    clear()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    add_save()
    MsgBox("Saved Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
End Sub
Private Sub clear()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    TextBox6.Clear()
    TextBox7.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        Me.TblteacherloadTableAdapter1.FillBy(Me.TblteacherloadDataSet2.tblteacherload)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You post all of your code (which, by the way, isn't really necessary) and don't point out **where** the error occurs?  Better to post the relevant part of you code where the error occurs.  95% of the folks on this site don't have the time or inclination to go through your code trying to guess where the error occured.

Comment: As a follow up, I think the `ToDataGrid` method on the `database` object is probably the place you need to start.  The exception is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Tim the error occured sir on the 'Me.Name = "frmTeacherload"' of the vb generated code sorry I forgot to post it..I tried debugging but the  error hinders me to process the design view of my code.. I hope you can help me thanks

Comment: that location doesnt match the error message

Comment: @Plutonix it is where the underline comes out sir.. Thanks

Comment: the Me in `Me.Name` is a form which does not match the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` in the error message.  you have one or the other wrong.

Comment: @Plutonix that is why I am wondering sir where does this error comes out because i do not have a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` on my either of my codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
Me.Name = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
```

You have a column on your DataGridView control named "Name" and the form has a property named "Name".
When the designer finds the line above it thinks that that's the property Name of the form.

If you look down the designer code you'll find this other line

```
Me.Name = "frmTeacherload"
```

To fix that error you have to rename the column.

Comment: To be more exact, `Me.Name` expects a `String`, not a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

Comment: This solved the same problem for me, too. Thank you!